# Java - Use predicate without lambda expressions

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, method-reference

I've below requirement:-

**Employee.java**

```
public boolean isAdult(Integer age) {
    if(age >= 18) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Predicate.java**

```
    private Integer age;
Predicate<Integer> isAdult;

public PredicateAnotherClass(Integer age, Predicate<Integer> isAdult) {
    this.age = age;
    System.out.println("Test result is "+ isAdult(age));
}

public void testPredicate() {
    System.out.println("Calling the method defined in the manager class");

}
```

Now My goal is to test whether the **age** which i pass to `Predicate` is adult or not using the method defined in `Employee` class , for which i am passing the method reference which i pass in the constructor of `Predicate` class.

But i don't know how to call the method defined in `Employee` class, below is my test class :-

```
public class PredicateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PredicateManager predicateManager = new PredicateManager();

        PredicateAnotherClass predicateAnotherClass = new PredicateAnotherClass(20, predicateManager::isAdult);
        predicateAnotherClass.testPredicate();;
    }
}
```

I am getting the compilation error in the `System.out.println("Test result is "+ isAdult(age));` in the `predicate` class.

Let me know how to resolve this issue. and if i need to provide any other information.

Comment: this is really confusing, shouldn't `Predicate<Integer> isAdult` be `Predicate<Employee> isAdult`. you do care if the employee is an adult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicate interface has method `test()`. You should use this method in a following way:

```
isAdult.test(age)
```

This method evaluates this predicate on the given argument. It returns true if the input argument matches the predicate, otherwise false

Comment: just found it by myself but still going with upvote and accepting your answer, thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 6):

This looks a little bit suspicious, you *care* if the employee is an adult, so your method should really take a `Employee` as an argument and a `Predicate<Employee>`, like this:

```
 private static void testEmployee(Employee emp, Predicate<Employee> predicate) {
    boolean result = predicate.test(emp);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

And the usage of this method would be:

```
testEmployee(new Employee(13), emp -> emp.isAdult(emp.getAge()));
```

The thing is you can reuse this method for *other* predicates as well, let's say you want to test gender, or income, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Predicate has test method, that is used, when working with streams/optionals.

```
public PredicateAnotherClass(Integer age, Predicate<Integer> isAdultFilter) {
    this.age = age;
    System.out.println("Test result is "+ isAdultFilter.test(age));
}
```

Comment: Please close the question, then.